# JAVA Класс с обработчиком событий, не разберусь с изменением названия кнопки

Tags: события, java

Только начал изучать Яву, создал 3 класса: главный, создание окна, обработчик.
Создается окно с кнопкой, при клике обработчик в отдельном классе должен переименовать её, но ничего не получается (пробовал вызывать диалоговое окно при нажатии кнопки работало, и когда обработчик был во внутреннем классе кнопка переименовывалась). Пробовал давать ссылку на кнопку, на класс и т.д. но не помогло.

**Главный класс**

```
public class cMain {
    // === Главный метод ===
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        cGui lGui = new cGui();
        lGui.mGui();
    }
}
```

---

**Тут создается окно**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class cGui {
    JFrame frame1;
    JButton button_obzor;
    JPanel panel1;
    JList list1;
    JScrollPane scroll1;
    JLabel label_numfiles;
    JFileChooser file_obzor;
    // === Метод описывающий окно ===
    public void mGui () {
        // === Ссылаемся на объекты
        frame1 = new JFrame("Easy reName");
        panel1 = new JPanel();
        button_obzor = new JButton("Обзор");

        // === Параметры
        // Фрейм
        frame1.setSize(800,600);
        frame1.setVisible(true);
        frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Кнопки
        button_obzor.setLocation(20,20);
        button_obzor.setSize(100,30);

        // Панель
        panel1.setLayout(null);
        panel1.setBackground(Color.white);

        // Список файлов
        String arraylist[] = new File("G:/Разное/Мусор/ИНШОП/изображения").list();

        // Создаем массив для имен файлов и даем длину найденных файлов в директории
        String[] arraylistname = new String[arraylist.length];

        // Перебираем и добавляем в массив
        for(int i = 0; i < arraylist.length; i++) {
            arraylistname[i] = arraylist[i];
        }

        // Создаем список
        list1 = new JList(arraylistname);

        // Скролл
        scroll1 = new JScrollPane(list1);
        scroll1.setSize(400,400);
        scroll1.setLocation(150,20);
        scroll1.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

        // Надписи
        label_numfiles = new JLabel("Кол-во: "+arraylist.length);
        label_numfiles.setSize(100,10);
        label_numfiles.setLocation(570,20);

        // === Добавляем объекты (сначало куда, а потом что)
        frame1.add(panel1);
        panel1.add(button_obzor);
        panel1.add(scroll1);
        panel1.add(label_numfiles);

        // === Вешаем обработчики
        button_obzor.addActionListener(new cEvent());
    }
}
```

---

**Обработчик**

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class cEvent implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        button_obzor.setText("asdasd");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    button_obzor.setText("asdasd");
}
```

В классе `cEvent` не определено `button_obzor`, так что код даже не должен компилироваться. К счастью источник события можно получить из параметра `event`:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    ((JButton) event.getSource()).setLabel("asdasd");
}
```

PS. Имена классов принято начинать с большой буквы, чтобы отличать их от методов и переменных.

Comment: Спасибо все заработало, на setLabel Эклипс жалуется (но компилирует без ошибок), написал setText и стало нормально.

Про имена классов, да много читал как их именуют. Решил что буду писать например для класса впереди букву c, перед методом букву m, ссылкой на объект l, переменные как есть :)